# how to convert following sql query using criteria api?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have a query which is already written in a Repository extending JpaRepository. But I need to add logical operator here.

`select ac from Accounts ac where ac.userId = :userId and ac.accountId = :accountID`

Requirement is getting account details when either userId or accountId is provided by the client.

```
public interface GoalPlanRepository extends JpaRepository<GoalPlan, String>{

    @Query("select ac from Accounts ac where ac.userId = :accountID ")
    public List<Accounts> getCalculateRecurringAmount(@Param("accountID") String accountID, @Param("userId") String userId);
```

This is My repository. I am implementing this method in goalPlanDaoImplementation

```
    public List<Accounts> getCalculateRecurringAmount(String accountID) {


    //      CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    //        CriteriaQuery<Accounts> cq = cb.createQuery(Accounts.class);
    // 
    //        Root<Accounts> acc = cq.from(Accounts.class);
    //        
    //        Predicate accountIDPredicate = null;
    //        Predicate userIdPredicate = null;
    //        
    //        if(accountID != null) {
    //        accountIDPredicate = cb.equal(acc.get("accountID"), accountID);
    //        }
    //        
    //        if(userId != null) {
    //        userIdPredicate = cb.equal(acc.get("userId"), userId);
    //        }
    //        
    //       
    //        cq.where(accountIDPredicate, userIdPredicate);
    //        
    //        TypedQuery<Accounts> query = em.createQuery(cq);

              List<Accounts> goalPlan = null;
              goalPlan = goalPlanRepository.getCalculateRecurringAmount(accountID);
               return goalPlan;
            //return query.getResultList();




        }
```

commented section is what I tried doing. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completly sure if I understood you correct, but maybe this will help:

```
final ArrayList<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
if(accountID != null) 
    predicates.add(cb.equal(acc.get("accountID"), accountID));
}
if(userId != null) {
    predicates.add(cb.equal(acc.get("userId"), userId));
}

switch(predicates.size()){
case 0:
    return null;
    //or maybe just continue to return all accounts...
case 1:
    cq.where(predicates.get(0));
    break;
default:
    cq.where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
}
```