# Adding multiple arguments to criteria based on further conditions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to create a Hibernate query with criteria that dynamically changes based on further conditions

**Example**

> First, create criteria.
>
> if (condition 1 applies) {add another argument to the criteria}
>
> if (condition 2 applies) {add another argument to the criteria} else {add another argument to the criteria}
>
> Finally, get the result in a list.

I have this snippet so far.

Unfortunately, I haven't got provided with a test environment so I cannot test what happens if I put another `query.where` command after the first one. I'd like to use multiple `where` clauses, first always use one as a base, then add more if certain conditions met.

```
session = HibernateUtil.openSession();

CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyClass> query = cb
        .createQuery(MyClass.class);

Root<MyClass> root = query.from(MyClass.class);

query.select(root);
query.where(
        cb.and(
                cb.equal(root.get("dataPointId"), container.getDataPointId()),
                cb.equal(root.get("datapointSubNumber"), subnumber)
        )
);
```

I want to specifiy more where clauses based on conditions and get the result as a `List<MyClass>`.

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56634960/how-to-convert-following-sql-query-using-criteria-api/56644633#56644633

Comment: That does not do what I want. It does either crit A or B, I need base criteria + adding further arguments if certain conditions met.

Comment: Have a second look. It adds crit A and/or B to an ArrayList and finally puts all added crits in the where-function.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood what you want to do, but have a look at [criteriaBuilder.selectCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.Case.html)

Comment: what kind of conditions you want to check before extending the where clause? Do you have to execute the query multiple times?

Comment: I have to execute the query only one time, but it has to be a different query based on the conditions in the if-else section. I don't want to write the whole query multiple times because the base query is always the same, it's just when certain conditions met, I need to execute the query with a few more arguments added to the criteria.

Comment: the answer from @chaitzD would do the job. good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CriteriaBuilder` and pass an array of `Predicates` to it. While adding the predicates you can have your if-else based on conditions to build a dynamic list. You can have your complex logic and build predicates array accordingly.

Something like this:

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

if ( <some condition> ) {
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(<your query condition>));
} else {
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(<your query condition>));
}
```

And at last:

```
query.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray()));
```